# Ссылка с уникальным ID

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица в бд, на страницы каждый элемент таблицы выводиться в цикле с уникальным id, получается примерно так : Иван, Андрей, Антон, имена это ссылки на сообщение, тоесть в бд храниться сообщение от Ивана, Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатие на "Иван", открывалась страница с сообщением. Как правильно реализовать?
***_******_******_******_******_******_******_***__-

```
id   of         message             whom           email

1   azon    Почему меня забанили?   admin

2   anna    За что меня забанили??  admin   angers@mail.ru

3   addon   Я не нарушал правил!    admin   angers@mail.ru
```

Comment: А если два Ивана ?

Comment: ID 1  | Иван | Сообщение
ID 2  | Иван | Сообщение
ID 3  | Иван | Сообщение
-------------------------

Comment: Да хоть три. См [ответ][1].

  [1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/130431#130433

Comment: мм..просто я так понял, что поле id varchar и содержит имена пользователей, я это хотел уточнить. Сорри если че. А так, поддерживаю @knes - а.

Comment: varchar id не самый лучший вариант: по чиселкам бегает шустрее. Хотя полностью исключать возможность использования нельзя, но чаще всего там хэш в таком случае.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

users:

USER_ID | USER_NAME
1       |   Иван
2       |   Андрей
3       |   Антон
4       |   Сергей

messages

Message_id | User_id | text

Нормализация - наше все. =)

```
//Выборка сообщений
'Select `text` from `messages` where `user_id`='.intval($_GET['id']);
//
//Выборка ссылок
$res = mysql_query('select `USER_ID`,`USER_NAME` from `users`');

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
  pritf('<a href="?id=%d">%s</a>',$row->USER_ID,$row->USER_NAME);
}
```

Comment: Зачем сообщениям айдишник? Не нужен, если выборка всегда будет по ВСЕМ сообщениям юзера. Но нужен, если понадобится запросить ссылку на какое-то одно.

Comment: Вывод : 202020202020

Comment: Таблицы в студию. первые три строки достаточно.

Comment: Добавил сверху

Comment: fetch_object лучше без особой надобности не использовать. Будь там 1000 юзеров, всю память выжрет

Comment: Не выжрет. Он же рядами жрет. Или я что-то не так говорю?

Comment: Вывод : 202020202020// Вот это у вас откуда вышло? =)
Мне нужны ваши таблицы БД =)

Comment: это браузер не понимает кириллицу. Подозреваю, что в href -e ссылки вместо цифры строковая значение.В utf8 перекодируйте ваш php файл